# Push data from API to existing page (combining data sources) in Eleventy

Tags: javascript, nunjucks, eleventy

I am trying to take an external URL added into a page's front matter --> send URL to scraper --> have scraper take metadata attributes --> push metadata attributes back to page's front matter.

So far the scraper is working, but how would I be able to push this data to the page? Getting the error:

```
TemplateContentRenderError was thrown
[eleventy:dev] > (./src/index.njk)
[eleventy:dev]   TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Here is the current code that I have:

```
config.addCollection('products', collection => {

// This is typical Collection by Tag call
const products = collection.getFilteredByTag('products');

// Map over all the posts
const postsWithUpdates = products.map(item => {

    // get URL from each page and pass it into scraper
    const itemMeta = getMetaData(item.data.refUrl).then((data) => {

        // map each page data with data from the scraper
        item.description = data.description;
        item.Image = data.icon;
        // item.date = item.data.post ? new Date(item.data.post.date) : item.date
        console.log(item.description);

        return item;
    });

    console.log(itemMeta);
    return itemMeta;
});


return postsWithUpdates;
});
```

When I console.log `itemMeta` or `postsWithUpdates` it returns as `Promise { <pending> }`

Any and all insight is very much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the mixing of synchronous code and asynchronous code with promises. If you're not familiar with promises, MDN has a [great guide on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

Essentially, a Promise is a way to run some code later after a task has been completed. This is helpful when you're waiting for another process, such as a network request, to finish.

Here, `getMetaData()` returns a Promise, where you can handle the data in the `then` handler. However, the code after that (the console.log and return) **do not** wait for the task to complete, which is why you see `Promise { <pending> }` logged out.

To fix this, you'll want to switch to `async`/`await` syntax. Luckily for us, [Eleventy supports `async` functions in `addCollection`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#advanced-custom-filtering-and-sorting).

```js
// We need to add the `async` keyword to enable `await` syntax.
config.addCollection('products', async (collection) => {

const products = collection.getFilteredByTag('products');

// When mapping over the posts, we also need to
// add the `async` keyword to the callback function.
// This will return an array of Promises.
const postsWithUpdates = products.map(async (item) => {

    // Now we can use the `await` keyword! This will wait for the
    // task to complete and place the result in `itemMeta`.
    const itemMeta = await getMetaData(item.data.refUrl)

    // map each page data with data from the scraper
    item.description = itemMeta.description;
    item.Image = itemMeta.icon;
    // item.date = item.data.post ? new Date(item.data.post.date) : item.date
    console.log(item.description);    

    console.log(item);
    return item;
});

// Since we now have an array of Promises, we need to resolve each
// one to their final values. We can do this with `Promise.all`.
// Don't forget to `await` the call!
return await Promise.all(postsWithUpdates);

});
```

Learn more about [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).